# Selecting an element from a list

Tags: scheme, racket

how would you design a  function `find` that that would take in a list of symbols, and a number, and returns the nth symbol of the list

I guess the output would be this

```
(find (list 'a 'b 'c 'd) 3)
```

> 'd

```
(find (list 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e 'f) 4)
```

> 'e

is there a simple way to do this that won't confuse me and is easy to understand using beginning student?

Comment: I assume you can't use `list-ref`?

Comment: You should be able to attack the problem through first principles.  Use the Design Recipe.  The main recursion will focus on the number, rather than on the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function already exists and is [standard](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_640), it's called [`list-ref`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._list-ref%29%29):

```
(list-ref (list 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e 'f) 4) 
=> 'e
```

From the documentation:

> `list-ref` returns the element of lst at position pos, where the list’s first element is position 0. If the list has pos or fewer elements, then the exn:fail:contract exception is raised.